# Can't pass argument to threading function

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a threading function and pass a string in.

```
def Function(data):
    while True:
        print(data)

data = "hello"
thread = threading.Thread(target=Function, args=data)
thread.start()
```

I got this error Function takes one positional argument but 5 were given. How can I pass a string in?

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=Function, args=(data, ))`

Comment: Notice that the name is `args`, not `arg` -- it expects a sequence of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

use a lambda function:

```py
thread = threading.Thread(
    target=lambda: Function("put args here")
)
```

lambda functions are just like regular functions, although it's anonymous.

```py
lambda: Function("put args here")
```

is equal to

```py
def unknown_func():
    Function("put args here")
```

read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp), this isn't the official documentation though